# Next-i18next double render

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I am working on a react+next project using the next-i18next package for localization.

I noticed an intermittent issue that seems to be occurring in both Chrome and FF and looks to be related to the next-i18next package itself. When any page is initially loaded, it looks like the pages are occasionally rendered twice. This seems to be only occurring for me on the client side (does not make a new GET request). Has anyone else run into this?

This can be reproduced by duplicating the simple example found in the next-i18next package and inserting a console.log in the main component in any page (Homepage and SecondPage components in the example). Doing a hard refresh on the page a few times (less than 10 in my case) is usually sufficient to show the console.log displaying twice on the client side. In these cases the server will show only a single log message, while the client shows the log message twice.

This also seems to happen in both dev and prod mode. However, double render is happening on every reload in FF with prod mode.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.